# Executing a ELF binary without creating a local file?

Tags: linux, elf

Is it possible to execute a binary file without copying it to hard drive?

I know `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` can load arbitrary binaries, but that still requires a locally stored file, my thought was to allocate a memory region, duplicate the contents to memory and execute it.

So is that possible?

Comment: Can't you simply use a disk-less file system like `tmpfs` ?

Comment: I don't know if you can get around making a writable page executable in user space. Maybe a setuid 'launch' program could work.

Comment: Take a look at the source of UPX compressor.

Answer (score 0):

> my thought was to allocate a memory region, duplicate the contents to memory and execute it.

For a statically-linked `a.out`, you *can* do just that.

For a dynamically-linked one, you'll need something like [dlopen_phdr](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11767).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but very difficult.  I worked on a similar problem years ago [here](http://hurd.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/hurd/gnumach-otop/linux/i386/ptest.c?revision=1.5&view=markup).  (Caution!  That code is incomplete and contains serious bugs.)

The hard part is to make sure that your process's address space requirements do not conflict with the binary's or the dynamic linker's (e.g., /lib/ld-linux.so.2).  If you control both programs' memory layout (because you linked them) you can avoid that problem.  (My code does not assume such control, and it takes pains to move itself out of the way if necessary.)

If there are no address space conflicts, it is a matter of allocating memory for the exe's PT_LOAD segments (and the linker's, if any), aligning and copying the segments in, protecting the read-only segments, allocating stack, initializing stack and registers [the way the kernel does](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html), and jumping to the exe's or linker's entry address.

Comment: Interesting... This assumes you want to directly execute the code from where it is. I guess it would be much easier if you allowed a copy *in memory*, such that the new process would have a completely independent memory layout.